# UITabBarController set selected MORE BUTTON

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

how can I switch to more button on UITabbarController in code, I want to make UITabController set selected view to more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

```
[myTabBarController setSelectedViewController: [myTabBarController moreNavigationController]];
```

Comment: Please don't respond with "not working" after less than _one_ minute. It means you've just copy&paste'd without trying anything on your own. `selectedIndex` is the property that allows you to set a tab programmatically. Try it!

Comment: silution is [self.tabBarController setSelectedViewController: self.tabBarController.moreNavigationController];